# Custom cursor wrong position after scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor-position

I'm trying to get one of those fancy circular cursors with a following outside ring, that changes when you hover an image for example.

I found most of the code already built on codepen, but when i applied to a longer page, the cursors seems to be off by few too many pixels to be visible. It works fine until you start scrolling, as the scroll increases so does the offset and makes it pretty much useless if you scroll, you can't see the cursor.

Here is a modified codepen: https://codepen.io/miguelpppires/pen/xxKLreP

I'm almost 100% sure this is the issue, but i have no idea how to fix it:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {

$('.cursor, .follower').css({
"transform": "translate3d(" + (e.pageX) + "px, " + (e.pageY) + "px, 0px)"
});
```

Any and all help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `clientX` and `clientY`, becuase `pageX` and `pageY` take the offset from the top of the page and `clientX` and `clientY` take the offset from the top of the viewport.

```
$('.cursor, .follower').css({
   "transform": "translate3d(" + (e.clientX) + "px, " + (e.clientY) + "px, 0px)"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved issue using  pageX and pageY insted of clientX and clientY.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved issue using pageX and pageY insted of clientX and clientY.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).